# How to use modeswitch

Tags: 12.04, usb, 3g

I have a 3G data card. On my Windows system I can access its memory, but I can't access the memory of the device. So I have a few questions:

- How I can access memory of my data card on Ubuntu 12.04?
- Why is my device not behaving plug n play?
- What is USB modeswitch?
- How to use it?

Here is the output of the command `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b159 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:231d Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
```

Answer (score 0):

**Usb Modeswitch**

When a USB Modem device with drivers for other OS is plugged in, first it is recognized as Flash device. after identifying the device, this mode is switched to Mass Storage or Modem device. This switching is done by USB Modeswitch.

You can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data
```

No need to run it. It works automatically.

To plug and play a device, you should install usb-modeswitch

**Accessing the Data**

You can access the data with applications like **Wammu** or **Gmobile Media**

Wammu

```
sudo apt-get install gammu wammu
```

Gmobile Media

```
sudo apt-get install gmobilemedia
```

In Ubuntu 13.10 there is a application called **modem-manager-gui**

```
sudo apt-get install modemmanager modem-manager-gui
```